# How to convert iPhone 12 raw audio to sound pressure level?

Tags: sound, analog-to-digital

I have 'raw' audio files recorded from an iPhone 12 Pro Max. I'd like to convert the raw 16 bit .wav amplitude to SPL. It's been a while since I was doing this kind of stuff hands-on and I was never an expert, but I think what I need to know is 1) the ADC input range and 2) the microphone sensitivity (mv/Pa). Are these known? Or perhaps has someone just measured with a reference system? People obviously know how to get dB SPL from phones somehow to make sound level meter apps.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13071120/2052625) suggests that it may not be possible to recover SPL due to automatic gain control, but I'm told that this file was recorded without any processing (filtering etc.) which I assume includes gain control.

Comment: A sound file can't have an SPL, there is absolutely no correlation.

Comment: @Tetsujin My terminology is probably sloppy. At each point in time, there is an air pressure value at the microphone diaphragm, which is converted to a voltage by the transducer, which is converted to a 16 bit value by the ADC. I have the 16 bit values, and I want the air pressure values.